# What type of screw should I use to install a latch lock on a metal door?

Tags: doors, screws, lock

I want to install a latch lock on a metal door.

What is the best type of screw for that?

Comment: There are a few ways to go, depending on how secure you want the connection to the door and what you mean by a "latch lock" there are many kinds of latches that lock out there. Hasps, barrel bolts, thumb turns, dead bolts. I would expect you mean a surface mount? Typically when bought new the proper screws are in the packaging.

Comment: I self drilling sheet metal screw is probably what I would look for. Do you have photos of the door and the latch you intend to hang?

Answer (score 1):

I would rivet it. Do not mess with screws. Rivets are much more simple and will hold the latch tight.

Answer (score 0):

The self tapping sheet metal screw is a great option if not available you can use a regular sheet metal screw and drill a very small pilot hole for them they will work just fine the only other option I can really see is to actually lag bolt them through the door with nuts on the other side. Of course you would have to drill holes slightly larger than the bolts to go through the door for the last option to work.